# What is the best practice to develop Composer's library and main project simultaneously?

Tags: php, git, composer-php, phpstorm

I am trying hard to understand what is the best practice to use Git with main project development and library development. I will try to explain:
I am developing a project and a library simultaneously. Both of them are on the GitHub. And here is my current workflow:

1. Make a change in the library
2. Commit and push it to the GitHub, make a release and update on Packagist
3. Run `composer update` in the main project, so that the new version of the library will be downloaded
4. Make a test with the new library version

That is too complicated and not right. What is a workout for this problem? I have an option:

- Define a library as a local repository and place this definition in the main project's composer.json file. *But this is strange because then if I upload composer.json to the GitHub, it will contain local repo definition, which is not right.*

Maybe there is some smart and cool method to get rid of this problem, but I don't know about it. Please explain how to do this. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am using PhpStorm, maybe it has an option that may help us to solve the problem.

Comment: *"if I upload composer.json to the GitHub, it will contain local repo definition, which is not right"*, so... don't do that? Using a local repository path is pretty standard practice if you're working on a project and library at the same time.

Comment: Well, I need to upload composer.json every time I add a new dependency, for example.

Comment: So just commit the changes you need, and not the `repositories` block - you don't need to push the whole file

Comment: And what about requiring a local repo? It requires dev-master version, while remote repo will require release version...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you often update the library that your main project uses you should consider hosting it as a local repository.

You can add a repository using composer CLI (see [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#modifying-repositories)) but it's much more simple to just update the `composer.json` file manually.

Open your `composer.json` file and find the `repositories` attribute (if it's not there create it in the root scope).

It should be an array of objects and every object should have a type (vcs for Version Control System) and an url.

Also add your library to `require`. You could use git version tags if you desire, but pointing to `dev-master` is a very common practice.

```
{
    "name": "mainproject",
    "description": "Main project development",
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "ssh://git@my-git-server-url.com/library.git"
    }],
    "require": {
        "library/library": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

When you have updated your library (and pushed the changes to the repository) you can simply run `composer update library/library` from your main development project to get all changes from your library.